# Is there an SQL Server equivalent for C# double.Epsilon and float.Epsilon ?

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, epsilon

Does `SQL Server` define epsilon constants for `float` and `real` types ?
In other words,  a value which is small enough to be considered as insignificant ?

in C#, there are `double.Epsilon` and `float.Epsilon` constants for that.
Unfortunately, they are too small to be used in SQL Server (which AFAIK consider them as equal to 0).

```
//C#
public struct Single
{
    public const float Epsilon = (float)1.4e-45;
}

public struct Double
{
    public const double Epsilon  = 4.9406564584124654E-324;
}

//SQL Server
select CAST('4.9406564584124654e-324' AS float) //returns 0
select CAST('1.4e-45' AS real) //returns 0
```

Comment: I guess you probably mean "too pricise" instead of "too small". But yeah SQL Server won't hold data to that precision, which makes me ask... why does it matter? If it can't store numbers that precise, then you won't be using numbers that precise, so why do you care?

Comment: I would like to filter out some values which has been stored in a SQL column which are non insignificant (considered as equal to zero while not exactly zero).
Something like `SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE ABS(SomeColumn) > @magicconstant`

Comment: You need to increase precision of you data so SQL server does store actual values you can use decimal type that allows you to define precision or you can just store your values with a shift - multiplied by 10^6 or something.

Comment: Well the docs say float will allow as low as `2.23E-308`, but if **your** decided cutoff point is `4.9406564584124654E-324` then surely that means that **all storable floats** in SQL Server **are** significant?

Comment: The point I am making is basically that it is you (and the requirements of your task)  that should define what is significant and what isn't

Comment: @musefan : I totally agree with you. Where did you find those constants ?

Comment: @tigrou: I got them [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)